# Area 51 Site is quite different from other SE sites and needs an SE footer

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, area-51

Honestly, navigation through Area 51 is a bit confusing and seems to be much different from the other SE sites.

The feature that is very lacking is the footer with all the sites you are subscribed to so that a user can easily return to a different SE site. This one really bugs me.  Can this be easily fixed?

Also, unlike all the other sites there is no "meta" site to add comments specifically about that site.

Again Area 51 seems out of sync with the other SE sites.

Comment: It is very different -- it's an entirely separate codebase that just happens to look somewhat the same. Adding the footer links is a good idea though

Comment: The link at the bottom of every SE site (except Area 51) is not the list of the sites where you are subscribed, but a list of the main SE sites.

Answer (score 5):

The "meta" for Area 51 is under the [discuss](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/) link at the top right of the page.

[image: Area 51 "meta"]

However, it's not called meta as it does more than just act as a site to report bugs and feature requests. It's a place to discuss the proposals themselves.

Comment: Can this be changed to  "meta" to be consistent with standard SE site terminology?

Comment: @mdpc discuss.area51 serves a dual purpose.  It is not solely a meta site.

Answer (score 3):

Area 51 is not a normal member of the Stack Exchange network.  It bears some similarities, but it's not a Q&A site and operates very differently.  I'd suggest starting at the [Area 51 FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) to get an idea what's going on.

For getting between the sites, you're better off using the Network Aggregator at the top of the page (the StackExchange logo in the upper left).  That exists on all the sites, and the All Sites tab actually shows *all* of the sites (unlike the footer), with the ones you are using at the top.

The footer links aren't really meant to be used to get around, since they don't include all the sites (they're more of a, "Did you know?").  They are not guaranteed to be on all of the sites in our network (they do not appear on stackexchange.com or area51).